# Add delay in processing the msmq requests

Tags: c#, queue, msmq

I have to keep some delay in processing MSMQ requests. Whatever the request went to queue, it should not process immediately it has wait for 1 or 2 mins. Is there any way to achieve this by changing the configurations of MSMQ? Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: This has to be done by the program that is actually processing or writing to the queue. The MSMQ is just a means of transporting data and has no influence in how the data is being processed. If you can not control the programs that are using the queue you could make one that reads one queue, delays waits for a minute, then writes to another queue and use that as a workaround.